# How do OnModelCreating and non automatic Migrations relate?

Tags: entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

When I add a new table that has some relations to my database and then run `Add-Migration` I see that code is generated in the `Up` method to add the table and its relations. 
However, I prefer to define the relation using the fluent API in the `OnModelCreating` method. How do these two methods interact? Can I delete the code from the `Up` method that defines the relation for instance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each of them has completely different purpose:

- `OnModelCreating` is used for inline fluent-API definitions of your model. These definitions together with default conventions, data annotations and configuration classes forms the complete definition of the model.
- Explicit migration defines what must be done to database to migrate it to the form required by your current model

Now, how those two relate? Migration has two inputs which are used to generate migration code (`Up` and `Down` methods). One input is the last migration record stored in `__MigrationHistory` table in the database. This record contains serialized model representing the database. This input is optional because first migration must work without it. The second input is mandatory - it is your current model which is retrieved by executing the code in your current assembly => `Add-Migration` will execute your `OnModelCreating` to get the current model and compare it with the model retrieved from the database. The result of comparison is content of `Up` and `Down` methods in the explicit migration.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand correctly the code in the `Up` method will reflect the definitions set in the `OnModelCreating` method (supposing that you added a Migration after writing the fluent API definition of course). One must *not* remove these reflected definitions from `Up`.

Comment: What would be the best way to inject code into the migrations code using `OnModelCreating`'s `ModelBuilder`? Would that be `HasAnnotation`?