# AutoMapper Queryable Extensions with Entity Framework - how to get OUTER joins?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have a Job entity with an optional Contract child entity (using Entity Framework)

```
    public class Job
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Guid? ContractId { get; set; }
        public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contract
    {
        public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following DTO

```
    public class JobDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ContractStartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I project to the DTO using AutoMapper Queryable extensions.

```
c.CreateMap<WorkTask, WorkTaskDtoLite>();

var jobDtos = _context.Jobs.ProjectTo<JobDto>().ToList();
```

Then this generates INNER joins, so does not return any JobDtos where there is no Contract. I need OUTER joins...

I'm really not sure how to fix this. I have referred to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions but this does not seem to address this basic issue.

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks all but seems to be an underlying issue with Entity Framework Core RC1.

See bug report here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3186

With suggested work-around here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/c4e44471b6f41f96d37b1acfbbb4cc97cd11ee89

Comment: For debugging, have you tried it without automapper? var jobDtos = _context.Jobs.Select(j => new JobDto { Title = j.Title, ContractStartDate = j.Contract.StartDate  }).ToList();

Comment: Yes it is still an INNER join...

Comment: It should do a left join when the FK is nullable. I don't work with GUIDs, but if you check the DB is it defined as nullable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000345/allow-null-foreign-key-guid

Comment: Yes nullable guid. EF7 so could be a bug?

Comment: Haven't used 7 yet. You could maybe play with fluent config (HasDatabaseGeneratedOption, etc).

Comment: Have you tried setting `DateTime` to `DateTime?`. I don't see what you expect it to do when the DateTime is null (i.e. Contract is null). Projection is far more limited, so it might not cope with that by default, in which case what about `NullSubstitute`?